# Ansible: install multiple Python packages on a single session

Tags: pip, ansible

One of my playbooks contains a task that installs basic Python packages:

```
---
  -
    name: "Install Python packages: {{ python_packages_to_install }}"
    sudo: true
    pip: name={{ item }}
    with_items: python_packages_to_install
```

With the following list of packages:

```
-
  include: python_basics.yaml
  vars:
     python_packages_to_install:
       - virtualenv
       - pss
       - requests
       - comment-builder
       - boto
       - ansible
       - uwsgitop
       - gitpull
       - ipython
```

The task works correctly and installs the packages:

```
TASK: [common | Install Python packages: ['virtualenv', 'pss', 'requests', 'comment-builder', 'boto', 'ansible', 'uwsgitop', 'gitpull', 'ipython']] ***
ok: [push-prod-01] => (item=virtualenv)
ok: [push-prod-01] => (item=pss)
ok: [push-prod-01] => (item=requests)
ok: [push-prod-01] => (item=comment-builder)
ok: [push-prod-01] => (item=boto)
ok: [push-prod-01] => (item=ansible)
ok: [push-prod-01] => (item=uwsgitop)
ok: [push-prod-01] => (item=gitpull)
changed: [push-prod-01] => (item=ipython)
```

The problem is that each line is executed using a consecutive SSH command, instead of installing all the packages in a single call.

**Is there a way to install multiple Python packages on an Ansible `pip` command?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Expanding on Ben's answer, you can also continue to preserve the package list as a yaml list like you have it, and do the projection to a single value when you pass it to the pip module like:

`pip: name="{{ python_packages_to_install | join(' ') }}"`

Keeps your playbook a little more maintainable...

Comment: I get a `msg: this module requires key=value arguments (['name=virtualenv', 'pss', 'requests', 'comment-builder', 'boto', 'ansible', 'uwsgitop', 'gitpull', 'ipython'])`. Something is probably wrong with stringifying the list.

Comment: A pair of quotes is needed - updating your answer.

Comment: Oh yeah- I actually tested it with the multiline dictionary syntax, but squashed it down to the shortcut syntax for the answer (which doesn't usually need the quotes unless there's spaces, depending on Ansible version). Thanks for the fix. ;)

Comment: @MattDavis Better to use the YAML syntax, Ansible's key=value syntax is quite hacky and fragile.

Comment: @augurar so I've heard (I'm on the Ansible core engineering team ;) )

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with Ansible 2.7 - I get the error ```fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "cmd": [
        "/usr/local/bin/pip2", 
        "install", 
        "openshift==0.8.4 boto3==1.5.20 botocore==1.8.50"
    ]```.  Problem is that `pip` gets a single argument with all 3 packages, rather than one argument per package.  Using a loop instead may be a bit slower but more likely to work.

Answer (score 10):

The multi-python package installation is now supported by the Ansible pip module.

```
- name: Install multi python packages
  pip:
    name:
      - virtualenv
      - pss
      - requests
      - comment-builder
      - boto
      - ansible
      - uwsgitop
      - gitpull
      - ipython
```

With version specifiers:

```
- name: Install multi python packages with version specifiers
  pip:
    name:
      - django>1.11.0,<1.12.0
      - bottle>0.10,<0.20,!=0.11
      - numpy==1.22.4
```

ref: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/pip_module.html

If this answer was helpful, kindly give it an upvote.

Answer (score 3):

Unlike Ansible `apt` module, [the `pip` module](http://docs.ansible.com/pip_module.html) does not accept a comma-delimited list of packages. Instead, you can provide all the package names as a space delimited string, using the `==` syntax to specify versions:

```
python_packages_to_install: "virtualenv==1.11.6 pss requests comment-builder boto ansible uwsgitop gitpull ipython"
```

If you're like me it may strike you as ugly and impractical to manage. An alternative is to use the `requirements` option in the pip module to specify a requirements file. Of course you'll need to create the requirements file first, probably using a template.